# Answer to own questions

Tags: feature-request

Can we please prevent that someone who asks a question can answer his own question?

A lot of workarounds get posted which are not ideal and may cause  issues in the future

Comment: Just leave a comment.

Comment: that is generelly ok for me that ppl can answer, see like [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/767837/dell-poweredge-r720xd-outputs-a-typical-fan-noise) as the author answered in the comment section maybe because he did not know better

Answer (score 5):

Anyone can ask and answer questions. Self answering is generally encouraged to the point that there is a box to tick when asking a question that allows you to add an answer before the question is posted.

[image]

As with any answer that is less than useful/ideal - downvote it, move on, the world turns.